# Entity Framework with Oracle - Edmmapping

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-6

I'm working with the Entity Framework 6 on an Oracle legacy database.
The EF maps for example Number(1) automatically to bool or Number(2) to byte, but I need to have them all as Int32.

I have added the edmMappings block to the app.config like described by Oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E56485_01/win.121/e55744/entityDataTypeMapping.htm#BABGBJCI
But it doesn't work, it always generates bool and int16 instead of int32

My Mapping in the app.config:

```
<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <edmMappings>
        <edmNumberMapping>
          <add NETType="int32" MinPrecision="1" MaxPrecision="1" DBType="Number" />
          <add NETType="int32" MinPrecision="2" MaxPrecision="3" DBType="Number" />
          <add NETType="int32" MinPrecision="4" MaxPrecision="5" DBType="Number" />
          <add NETType="int32" MinPrecision="6" MaxPrecision="10" DBType="Number" />
          <add NETType="int64" MinPrecision="11" MaxPrecision="19" DBType="Number" />
        </edmNumberMapping>
      </edmMappings>
      <dataSources>
        <dataSource alias="SampleDataSource" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ORCL))) " />
      </dataSources>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
```

I tried different things in this block, but nothing changes. Is there something else I need to configure?

Comment: Did you figure out a solution to your problem? I'm stuck with the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I remove the reference "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" from the package and set the reference to the installed driver from the Oracle Developer tools (C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle Developer Tools for VS2015\odp.net\managed\common\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll). Then the mapping is going.

Comment: What I understood from this answer is that you removed the NuGet packages that installed the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll and instead installed the dll from Oracle Visual Studio Developer Tools manually through Add Reference and it worked. Is this correct? I did this exact procedure but sadly the EdmMappings are still not taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

In case you didn't do this already: in addition to the edmMappings I think you have to **change the type of your properties in your model entities** as well. E.g. in Visual Studio, open the model diagram (*.edmx) right click the property with type Number(X) in your database, open Properties and change 'Type' to the type you want.

Comment: Try to make the answer clear by highlighting the crucial information.